# How do I populate a combo box with a column from my sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How do I populate a combobox with a column from MySQL database?

```
private void comboBoxSender_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT Sender FROM Messages";
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        comboBoxSender.DisplayMember = "Sender";
        comboBoxSender.ValueMember = "Sender";
        comboBoxSender.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
    }
    catch (Exception combo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(combo.ToString());
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

This is the code which I have at the moment; but none of the data is showing up. Can someone please help I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: Do you have any errors/exceptions?

Comment: No, but when I run the program and click the combo box there are not options for me to select

Comment: Use ds.Tables[0] instead of ds.Tables[1]

Comment: You say `MySQL` in your title, but the code uses `SqlCommand` which is for Microsoft **SQL Server** - so which is it now?? MySQL or SQL Server??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Sender FROM Messages", conn))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                comboBoxSender.ValueMember = "Sender";
                comboBoxSender.DisplayMember = "Sender";
                comboBoxSender.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are populating the same combo box on the selection change event eg `comboBoxSender`. This may get into loop and generate Stack-overflow exception.